# Excel VBA - Find all rows with a specific value and get their row number

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I have close to zero knowledge in excel and vba.
What I'm trying to do the the following:

```
for each row in ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SheetPotatoData")
    if cell (column 5):(row) value equals "potato"
        do something with (column 2):(row)
```

I would really appreciate it if you could enlighten me on the proper syntax to do this.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=get+range+value+vba&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-GB:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active&gfe_rd=cr&ei=3Ia9V8XpKZDCaPvoj6gC&gws_rd=ssl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html

```
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableNameHere").ListRows.Count
    If Cells(i,5).Value = "potato" Then
        Cells(i,2).Value = "New value"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for not giving me a link to a google search :) This is exactly what I was looking for! I simply replaced the 50 with ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableNameHere").ListRows.Count and it loops on the whole table now.

Comment: Updated answer with `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableNameHere").ListRows.Count`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just add "`.DataBodyRange.Rows`" to the end of the first line in your line "For... Each" structure.  You're asking VBA to iterate through each `Row` in a `ListObject`, rather each `Row` in the collection of `Rows` contained *within* the `ListObject`.

That allows sticking with the more elegant, readable, and reliable 'For...Each' structure rather than fetching range bounds and traversing it using counters.  Using the `DataBodyRange` property of the list allows you to automatically handle any Header rows that may be present and not include them in your row inspection loop.  You can reference the `ListObject.Rows` collection instead if you want Headers included.

Final code would look something like:

```
For Each row In ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SheetPotatoData").DataBodyRows.Rows
    if row.Cells(1,5) = "potato"
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```